# Contexts for Emacs

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I've been playing with [Buffer Ring](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferRing) for Emacs and I really like the idea of having several rings of buffers.  However, I would like to go a bit further.  I go into what some may call "contexts".  I usually work on about three projects at once.  Often the projects involve different files and different languages.  Sometimes it's nice to have cedet windows in my frame along with a debugger window, sometimes they get in the way.  I would like to have a context for each project so I can run a command and by buffer ring changes along with the frames.  I may also have a few misc contexts that aren't actually tied to projects like editing .emacs to include new packages and key bindings.

Is there an Emacs feature that can do these "contexts"?  It would be nice to have the contexts be preserved between sessions.

Answer (score 1):

With [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) you can bookmark the current "desktop" (the current state of buffers, windows, registers, search-ring, etc). Then at a later date you can jump to the bookmark to restore the saved state.

Since `desktop.el` doesn't know about the buffer ring, you'll probably have to customize `desktop-globals-to-save` appropriately.

(I've not used this myself, but it sounds like the kind of thing you're after.)

Comment: Sounds good.  I tried with `(setq desktop-globals-to-save (append 'buffer-ring-torus))` and get `desktop-save: Wrong type argument: sequencep, buffer-ring-torus`.  So I tried `(setq desktop-globals-to-save (append '(buffer-ring-torus))` and got `desktop-internal-v2s: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'`.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're a fairly novice Emacs user, you probably want to use `M-x customize-variable RET desktop-globals-to-save RET`. But if you insist on doing it in Lisp, try something like `(require 'cl) (pushnew 'buffer-ring-torus desktop-globals-to-save)`

Comment: Sounds like your trouble has nothing to do with bookmarks or Bookmark+.  Try separately solving your desktop problem, before adding desktop bookmarks to the mix. And yes, Customize is your friend, even if the UI leaves much to be desired.